# Using Bootstrap my nav bar is too long on mobile

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar, nav

I am having a little trouble with the code of my website https://bjmrq.github.io/foyer.html everything is fine on laptop but as soon as I go check it with my mobile the navbar seem to be too long ! If anyone could help me :) (i am using bootstrap 4)
Thanks for your time!

```
<nav id="mainNavbar" class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-sm fixed-top" style="background-color: #563d7c;">
<a class="navbar-brand navTitle mx-2" href="index.html"><span class="fas fa-camera-retro"></span>&nbsp; Sophie Madonna</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navLinks" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggle``r-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navLinks">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item mx-2">
      <a class="navbar navTitle nav-link" href="foyer.html"><span class="fab fa-gripfire"></span>&nbsp; Le foyer</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <li class="nav-item mx-2">
      <a href="about.html" class="nav-link">My Story</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item mx-2">
      <a href="contact.html" class="nav-link">Follow Me</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```
.navbar {
font-family: 'Ranga';
color: white;
font-size: 1.3em;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-brand .navbar-nav .nav-link .navTitle .navbar .navbar-dark {
font-family: 'Ranga';
color: white;
font-size: 1.3em;
}
```

[here is my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1qPp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<hr>` element just under the first `<h1>` tag has a set width `width: 500px;` which is causing the rest of the body to be pushed left on smaller screens.

Answer (score 0):

use class img-fluid for images

```
<div class="col-md-5 col-lg-5 col-12 col-sm-12">
<div class="heading-text">
<img src="/images/1/undraw_uploading_go67.svg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
</div>
</div>
```